# Set gnupg homedir in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gnupg

I sign my git commits with my private gpg key and changed my gnupg homedir on my linux mint system from `~/.gnupg` to `~/.config/gnupg` after the free desktop standard [XDG BASE Directory](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

When I commit some projects over the terminal, git knows that my keys are stored under the directory `~/.config/gnupg`, but IntelliJ does not know it.

I want to configure IntelliJ with the gpg option `--homedir ~/.config/gnupg`, but i can't find in the options settings to configure it.

How I can setup Intellij to use an other gpg home directory to sign my commits?

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for commits signing in IntelliJ - see [IDEA-110261](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261)

However, ItelliJ just invokes command line git, and if signing works from native OS command line (command prompt n Windows, Terminal in Mac, etc), it should work. You will probably need to enable signing by default, though, and adjust config a bit - see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127802#comment=27-1866498)